# How can I add a filter to the circle when it's inside the circle?

Tags: html, css

I created a clip-path circle, but the filter I added seems to be outside the parent element, but I couldn't find a solution. You can see it better from my codepen account. If there is a way to add box-shadow to clip-paths, then you can suggest a solution to the problem. Thank you in advance for your answers.
codepen: https://codepen.io/BerkayAkgurgen/pen/zYKgWXw

```css
.card {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    // overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: blue;
    filter: drop-shadow(-1px 6px 13px black);
}

    .circle {
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        background-color: red;
        opacity: 1;
        top: -150px;
        left:90px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Sass - Grid</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
         <div class="circle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you be more specific on what kind of shadow you want to get?

Comment: This is not important. Just how can ı add?

Comment: *how* to add *what* ? it's important to us to understand *what* you want to add if you want us to help.